# NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError for dynamic class in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a  in my HTML code that should have different classes that it gets from a variable.
The broughter picture: I have a panel as a mat-card I want to expand when hovered over it. The HTML code contains buttons that are own components. These buttons should get the information if the panel is expanded. The buttons get this info through the input `[isExpanded]="isPanelExpanded()"` I also have a "pin-button" that pins the panel so it is allways expanded

The HTML Code is

```html
<mat-card class="{{fastLaneClass}}" [ngStyle]="{'height': height}">
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="pin()" class="expand-button" [ngClass]="{'expand-button-active': isPinned, 'expand-button-visible': isExpanded}">
    <mat-icon style="font-size: 20px;">push_pin</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-card-content class="fast-lane-content">
    <div *ngFor="let button of fastlaneItems">
      <app-fastlane-button [item]="button" 
      (clicked)="onFastlaneItemButtonClicked($event, button)" 
      [isFastlaneClickEnabled]="isFastlaneClickEnabled" [isEnabled]="isButtonEnabled(button)" [isExpanded]="isPanelExpanded()">
      </app-fastlane-button>
      <div class="button-space"></div>
      <div *ngIf="button.isForwardButton">
        <hr>
        <div class="button-space"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

The function that returns the input for the buttons also sets the variable `fastLaneClass` that defines the class the card has.

This is the relevant Typescript Code:

```js
  isPanelExpanded() : boolean {
    const flp = document.querySelector('.fast-lane-panel')
    const isHover = flp?.matches(':hover');
    const isExpanded: boolean = (isHover || this.isPinned) ?? false;
    this.isExpanded = isExpanded;
    this.fastLaneClass = isExpanded ? 'infobar fast-lane-panel fast-lane-panel-expanded' : 'infobar fast-lane-panel';
    return this.isExpanded;
  }
```

Because i had problems with checking if the mouse position hovers over the object I just look up if the HTML Element has `:hover`.

When I hover over the object, even though everything works perfectly, it get this Error message:
`Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'infobar fast-lane-panel'. Current value: 'infobar fast-lane-panel fast-lane-panel-expanded'.`

I allready tried `[ngClass]="{'fast-lane-panel-expanded': isExpanded}"`, I allready tried having a function that returs either just the two or all three css classes. I tried everything I could come up, with the hope it would fix this.

Does somebody know what my mistake is?

Comment: The issue is that you are setting variables in a function that is triggered in the change detection of angular. Can you provide a full stackblitz example (also containing the definition of the other variables, so I can provide a solution? Short summary why this error appears: Angular notices something changed. It then rerenders your component and therefore calls "isPanelExpanded()". Since this function is changing input variables, angular knows something is changed by a change detection cycle itself and will therefore complain. A possible fix is to remove the changes to component variable here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Fabian Strathaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17298437/fabian-strathaus) I have found the problem. Like he said it is because the called function `isPanelExpanded()` changes the class variable `fastLaneClass` which makes Angular reload the `class="{{fastLaneClass}}"` property. So even though Angular thinks it knows what fastLaneClass is it changes while rendering.

I changed the class property to a function `getFastLaneClass()`:

```
<mat-card class="{{getFastLaneClass()}}" [ngStyle]="{'height': height}">
```

And instead of the variable `isExpanded` I now just use the function `isPanelExpanded`:

```
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="pin()" class="expand-button" [ngClass]="{'expand-button-active': isPinned, 'expand-button-visible': isPanelExpanded()}">
    <mat-icon style="font-size: 20px;">push_pin</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

The functions `isPanelExpanded()` and `getFastLaneClass()` now look like this:

```
  isPanelExpanded() : boolean {
    const flp = document.querySelector('.fast-lane-panel')
    const isHover = flp?.matches(':hover');
    const isExpanded: boolean = (isHover || this.isPinned) ?? false;
    return isExpanded;
  }

  getFastLaneClass() : string {
    return this.isPanelExpanded() ? 'infobar fast-lane-panel fast-lane-panel-expanded' : 'infobar fast-lane-panel';
  }
```